# How to watch new processes that are running or terminated in Visual C++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, process

I wonder how to watch new processes that are running or terminated. Can I do it with Windows 7 APIs? How?

I'm using Visual C++ in Windows 7 and don't want to use .Net Framework.

Comment: Can you describe the scenario? It's unusual to need to monitor all processes. Typically you should just leave processes alone.

Comment: @raymondchen I'm supposed to log the new running processes or terminated processes

Comment: But why are you supposed to log them?

Answer (score 2):

Whilst you can do this using polling (i.e. EnumProcesses), the best way to do it is an event driven approach. And to do that you need to use WMI. This [MSDN page gives sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390425.aspx).

**Update** Apparently you can use [Event Tracing for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803.aspx) as an alternative, but I personally know nothing about that.

Comment: WMI is not necessary.  Event Tracing for Windows is a more efficient alternative.  But it's also a PITA to program.

Comment: @arx I've never heard of event tracing. Thanks for the helpful comment.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Process32First` and `Process32Next` from Tool Help library. [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has an example how to obtain the list of running processes.

An alternative is [EnumProcesses function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).